# How do I display a Report or Report Chart on a VisualForce page on Opportunity page layout?

Tags: apex, visualforce

This SF page

```
<apex:page>
<analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

is giving me the below error:

```
Error: DMAI_Reports line 2, column 33: Open quote is expected for attribute "reportId" associated with an element type "analytics:reportChart"
```

Error   Error: Open quote is expected for attribute "reportId" associated with an element type "analytics:reportChart".

Comment: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm

Comment: Copy paste the code in notepad/ wordpad / notepad++ or some kind of text editor. The open quote in the reportid="" might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you were exactly right, charts are ugly but are showing up. I had to tag the Opp as the Standard Controller to add to Opp page layout? I have a matrix report - how do I display that via Visualforce? I cannot recreate that matrix output on a standard SF Chart...Thanks Rao!